# Unresolved reference trying to build .aar with kotlin mpp

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to get https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization to work with my android library I am building using kotlin mpp. This is my gradle file

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.3.61"
}

group = "org.greeting"
version = 1.0

android {
    compileSdkVersion(27)
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(15)
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Specify Kotlin/JVM stdlib dependency.
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7")
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib", org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION)) // or "stdlib-jdk8"
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.14.0") // JVM dependency


    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
    testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")

    androidTestImplementation("junit:junit:4.12")
    androidTestImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test")
    androidTestImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit")
}

kotlin {
    android("androidLib")

    val buildForDevice = project.findProperty("device") as? Boolean ?: false
    val iosTarget = if (buildForDevice) iosArm64("ios") else iosX64("ios")
    iosTarget.binaries {
        framework {
            // Disable bitcode embedding for the simulator build.
            if (!buildForDevice) {
                embedBitcode("disable")
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets["androidLibMain"].dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:0.14.0")
    }
    sourceSets {
        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:0.14.0")
            }
        }
        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common")
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.register("copyFramework") {
    val buildType = project.findProperty("kotlin.build.type") as? String ?: "DEBUG"
    dependsOn("link${buildType.toLowerCase().capitalize()}FrameworkIos")

    doLast {
        val srcFile = (kotlin.targets["ios"] as KotlinNativeTarget).binaries.getFramework(buildType).outputFile
        val targetDir = project.property("configuration.build.dir")!!
        copy {
            from(srcFile.parent)
            into(targetDir)
            include("greeting.framework/**")
            include("greeting.framework.dSYM")
        }
    }
}

tasks.register("iosTest") {
    val device = project.findProperty("iosDevice") as? String ?: "iPhone 8"
    dependsOn("linkDebugTestIos")
    group = JavaBasePlugin.VERIFICATION_GROUP
    description = "Runs tests for target 'ios' on an iOS simulator"

    doLast {
        val binary = (kotlin.targets["ios"] as KotlinNativeTarget).binaries.getTest("DEBUG").outputFile
        exec {
            commandLine("xcrun", "simctl", "spawn", "--standalone", device, binary.absolutePath)
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run build i get `Unresolved reference: serialization` on line `import kotlinx.serialization.ImplicitReflectionSerializer;` But if compile the androidTests the linking works fine.  Strangely i have to do `sourceSets["androidLibMain"]` and can't include it in the `sourceSet{}` block not sure if this is related. Any ideas on why the build task is not linking my serialization library? Thanks